# Azure DNS change not affected

Tags: domain-name-system, azure

I changed my A Record for your-voting.com to 85.13.135.154. But the Domain is redirecting to the old website. If i ping the domain your-voting.com, following happens:

> C:\Users\Niklas Raab>ping your-voting.com
>
> Ping wird ausgeführt für your-voting.com [52.174.7.133] mit 32 Bytes
>   Daten: Zeitüberschreitung der Anforderung. Zeitüberschreitung der
>   Anforderung. Zeitüberschreitung der Anforderung. Zeitüberschreitung
>   der Anforderung.
>
> Ping-Statistik für 52.174.7.133:
>       Pakete: Gesendet = 4, Empfangen = 0, Verloren = 4
>       (100% Verlust),

On Tracert:

> C:\Users\Niklas Raab>tracert your-voting.com
>
> Routenverfolgung zu your-voting.com [52.174.7.133] über maximal 30
>   Hops:
>
> 1     3 ms     1 ms     1 ms  fritz.box [192.168.178.1]   2    12 ms
>   12 ms    12 ms  ipbcc040fe.dynamic.kabel-deutschland.de
>   [188.192.64.254]   3     9 ms     9 ms    11 ms 
>   ip5886bf76.dynamic.kabel-deutschland.de [88.134.191.118]   4    16 ms 
>   12 ms    12 ms  ip5886c209.static.kabel-deutschland.de [88.134.194.9] 
>   5    11 ms    10 ms    13 ms  ip5886ca7c.static.kabel-deutschland.de
>   [88.134.202.124]   6    17 ms    17 ms    19 ms 
>   ip5886ca5c.static.kabel-deutschland.de [88.134.202.92]   7    21 ms
>   20 ms    24 ms  ip5886ca23.static.kabel-deutschland.de [88.134.202.35]
>   8     *        *        *     Zeitüberschreitung der Anforderung.   9 
>   32 ms    32 ms    32 ms  be-71-0.ibr02.fra30.ntwk.msn.net
>   [104.44.9.254]  10    33 ms    32 ms    32 ms 
>   be-5-0.ibr02.ams.ntwk.msn.net [104.44.5.17]  11    38 ms    33 ms
>   32 ms  be-3-0.ibr01.ams06.ntwk.msn.net [104.44.5.47]  12    30 ms
>   32 ms    31 ms  ae103-0.icr04.ams06.ntwk.msn.net [104.44.10.69]  13
>   *        *        *     Zeitüberschreitung der Anforderung.  14     *        *        *     Zeitüberschreitung der Anforderung.  15     *        *        *     Zeitüberschreitung der Anforderung.  16     *        *        *     Zeitüberschreitung der Anforderung.  17     *        *        *
>   Zeitüberschreitung der Anforderung.  18     *        *        *
>   Zeitüberschreitung der Anforderung.  19     *        *        *
>   Zeitüberschreitung der Anforderung.  20     *        *        *
>   Zeitüberschreitung der Anforderung.  21     *        *        *
>   Zeitüberschreitung der Anforderung.  22     *        *        *
>   Zeitüberschreitung der Anforderung.  23     *        *        *
>   Zeitüberschreitung der Anforderung.  24     *        *        *
>   Zeitüberschreitung der Anforderung.  25     *        *        *
>   Zeitüberschreitung der Anforderung.  26     *        *        *
>   Zeitüberschreitung der Anforderung.  27     *        *        *
>   Zeitüberschreitung der Anforderung.  28     *        *        *
>   Zeitüberschreitung der Anforderung.  29     *        *        *
>   Zeitüberschreitung der Anforderung.  30     *        *        *
>   Zeitüberschreitung der Anforderung.
>
> Ablaufverfolgung beendet.

The change is about 12 hours ago. And Azure normally changes the DNS very quickly. The TTL is set to 1 minute (only for testing). What is happening here?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the right nameservers? `dig +trace your-voting.com` shows that your nameservers are

```
your-voting.com.        172800  IN      NS      ns1.bdm.microsoftonline.com.
your-voting.com.        172800  IN      NS      ns2.bdm.microsoftonline.com.
your-voting.com.        172800  IN      NS      ns3.bdm.microsoftonline.com.
your-voting.com.        172800  IN      NS      ns4.bdm.microsoftonline.com.
```

Which are Office 365 nameservers. Azure nameservers look like:

```
ns1-04.azure-dns.com.
```

I know there are a lot of crossovers between Office 365 and Azure management, but I would be checking that you have made your DNS change in the correct place.

Comment: Now the lookup is going right, but no affect until now, probably some time to go! I will mark your answer, if it works!